# Fullcalendar async loading and display of event sources

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I've set up my events sources to pull from two different endpoints. One of these endpoints is heavy and happens to take two seconds longer than the other.

My calendar appears to wait until both sources are loaded before populating the calendar.

Q: is it possible to populate the calendar with the first data source while waiting for the second to finish?

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventSources: [
        loadQuickEvents,
        loadSlowEvents'
    ]
});

function loadQuickEvents (start, end, timezone, callback) {
    // execute xhr, on success trigger callback
    ...
    callback ()
}

function loadSlowEvents (start, end, timezone, callback) {
    // execute xhr, on success trigger callback
    ...
    callback ()
}
```

Comment: please can we see some code, thanks

Comment: @ADyson code sample added

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know that, but based on your question I made a demo - http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/229/ - which shows this occurring. I don't see how, via the documented API, it would be possible to change this behaviour. I suggest you raise a ticket on the fullCalendar GitHub site to understand whether this is the intended behaviour or whether its a bug, or whether an option could be provided to control it